# ListView Cell Translation manipulation affects other cells

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a custom `SwipeListView` which allows to swipe cells to the left or to the right, currently only for Android. This works perfectly fine, but for some reason changing `TranslationX` of the Cell's `ContentView` affects other cells in the `ListView`. Every 8th cell changes it's `TranslationX` too (at least visually):

[image: Swipe Bug]

This is the line of code which results in this behavior:

```
mainContent.TranslationX = quota * Width + mainContentPositionX;
```

I've tried some possible solutions, none of them worked:

- Try every different `CachingStrategy` for the `ListView` (RetainElement, RecycleElement, RecycleElementAndDataTemplate)
- Run code on MainThread
- After manipulating `TranslationX`, iterate through all other cells in my `ListView` and set their `TranslationX` to 0

I was sure the problem is that the cell is being reused and that's why it applies the `TranslationX` manipulation, but if it's that then I'm confused why using `CachingStrategy=RetainElement` doesn't solve the issue.

I will also we grateful for ideas which help be to debug this problem.

---

### Edit

I implemented the `SwipeListView` feature for iOS and it works without any problems. Seems to be an Android issue.

---

### Edit - Github Repository

### I have added a sample Github Repository: https://github.com/Zure1/SwipeListView-Sample

### Edit

I can now confirm that this is only a problem in Android. iOS works fine.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code please?

Comment: @Aaron what exactly do you mean by that? It's a `Xamarin` app and I only included one page, the custom `SwipeListView` and some CustomRenderers for Android.

Comment: It is definitely the reuse. If you could somehow hook up to the `BindingContext` change event for the cell, that would be a good place to put the reset swipe. Could you post some code or create a repo on GitHub?

Comment: @MartinZikmund added GitHub repo in my post

Comment: @DennisSchröer ostensibly this library would achieve what you're after and may save you some heartache - https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/ContextMenu

Comment: @MarkZhukovsky It looks very promising. I will try to contribute to that project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your analysis that the issue lies in item recycling. As you are changing the translation programmatically, the framework is not aware about your change and that you want it to be reverted so it keeps the translation as is. All the Caching Strategies involve item recycling including `RetainElement`. Recycling is better to stay enabled as it provides big performance gains.

A possible solution to your issue is to use data binding to set the `TranslationX` property and have the bound property on your ViewModel. This way the value reset whenever the control is recycled and bound to a new ViewModel. You can either introduce an integer property on your ViewModel and bind that to `TranslationX` or maybe the cleaner way is you introduce a Boolean property like `IsSwipped` and create a Data Trigger on that to set the translation as needed.

Comment: Good idea, but the problem I see with this is that in order to swipe, I first need to process the touch events of the view. So I don't see a way to let the ViewModel handle this, because it doesn't know when I'm swiping. I'm using the `DispatchTouchEvent` of the List and the Item to achieve the manipulation of `TranslationX`.

Comment: Yes you'd still keep the task of swipe detection in the View as it is a View concern. I think a solution might involve creating a custom behaviour (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/) that sets a property and data bindings can transfer the value to your ViewModel. I would advise you try the component/library suggested by Mark in the comments above first as it would be simpler to use it if it fulfils your needs.

Comment: Yeah I'm going with to contribute to that library Mark suggested. Some things are missing, but it looks a lot cleaner than my code and I could use a fresh start at this point, because the code base of my swipe project grew a lot since I opened this question! Thanks for your suggestion tho